# C# WCF Web Services - Two forms of binding/authenticating

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to build a WCF Webservice that can and will use NT Authentication OR a certificate?

Comment: You can have the same contract exposed over multiple endpoints, allowing you to configure each endpoint independently of the others.